# Access inner arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an arraylist of arraylist like following:

```
[[A,10],[B,20],[C,30]]
```

How do I access the inner arraylist's elements? Suppose I want to print C. How to print that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a list built from other lists. You can directly acces an element at a specific index with the [List.get(int)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#get(int)) method:

```
List<List<String>> list = new ArrayList<List<String>>();
list.get(2).get(0);
```

or iterate over your list:

```
for(List<String> innerList : list){

}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use from this code :

```
myArrayList.get(2).get(0)
```